# Using ST_Union to merge tables containing lines?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, postgis-2.0, merge, union

I have to build a street network with PostGIS that will be used with pgRouting.

I have two tables:

1. the_network (182 lines): is a `MULTILINESTRING` table. Having columns `"road_name"` (varchar),  `"road_length"` (numeric)
2. buildings (104 lines): is a `POINT` table. Having `"building_id"` (integer)

The following code creates lines between buildings and the network. The 104 created lines are stored in `"buildings_to_network_lines_table"` which is `GEOMETRY` type.

```sql
SELECT ST_ShortestLine(a.geom, ST_Collect(b.geom)) AS geom, 
       ST_Distance(a.geom, ST_Collect(b.geom)) AS shape_length INTO buildings_to_network_lines_table
FROM  buildings a, the_network b
WHERE ST_Dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, 1000)
GROUP BY by a.gid, a.geom;
```

[image: How to create a new table containing the black lines (the_network) and the red lines (buildings_to_network_lines_table)]

Then I just want to create one table named the_network_full that contains all the lines of the_network and buildings_to_network_lines_table tables. I've tried to achieve this by a `ST_UNION()` function:

```sql
SELECT ST_Union(a.geom, b.geom) AS the_network_full
FROM  the_network a, buildings_to_network_lines_table b;
```

[image: xample]

The results look good but unfortunately the resulting `"the_network_full"` table (type `GEOMETRY`) contains 18'928 lines (**`182*104`**) instead of **`182+104=286`** lines.

How can I merge these two tables into a new one?

Comment: Did you want a geometrical union? Seems like you want the union of tables: SELECT geom AS the_network_full
FROM  the_network 
UNION
SELECT geom AS the_network_full
FROM buildings_to_network_lines_table;

Answer (score 3):

You implicitly `CROSS JOIN`ed the tables so you got a cartesian product.
Since you don't want to merge the geometries together you should use the `UNION ALL` which is an entirely different construct:

```
SELECT a.geom
FROM  the_network a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.geom
FROM buildings_to_network_lines_table b
```

Now that you have a correct `SELECT` query you can use it in `INSERT ... SELECT` to put the data in new table.